# Unable to fetch data from SQL Server using JDBC on Raspbian (Works on Windows but not on Raspbian Jessie)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I wrote some code which is supposed to pull information from my SQL server to tell what item is currently running.
The code runs fine on my windows machine, however I plan on running this on a raspberry pi running Raspbian Jessie.  When I run the code it gives me the error

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host H79SQLMERINSQL, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".`

When I run my code on my windows machine, it runs completely fine and gives me the item number

Here is the code:

```
   public void main(String []args) {  

      // address of the SQL Server
      String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://H79SQLMERINSQL:1433;" +  
         "databaseName=runtime;user=sa;password=sa;";
      //ErrorDialog errors = new ErrorDialog();

      // Declaration of variables

      //JDBC objects 
      Connection conURL = null;  
      Statement statement = null;  
      ResultSet receivedStatement = null;

      //Variables for calling
      String itemNumber = null;   

      //The following code is where all of the SQL Server connections happen and the setting of variables for use later
      try {  
         // Establish the connection.  
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
         conURL = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);  
         System.out.println("Not Prblem");
         // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.  
         statement = conURL.createStatement();  
         receivedStatement = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Value "
         + "FROM v_StringLive "
         + "WHERE v_StringLive.TagName IN ('MD_ProcessData.ItemNumberMD1')");  

         // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.  
         while (receivedStatement.next()) {  
            itemNumber = receivedStatement.getString(1);
            //Below code is for displaying to the system
            /*System.out.println("The item number is: "+receivedStatement.getString(2) + " " + receivedStatement.getString(6));*/
         }  
      }  

      // Handle any errors that may have occurred.  
      catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error 101: Connection to SQL Server has timed out");
         e.printStackTrace();  
      }
      finally {  
         if (receivedStatement != null) try { receivedStatement.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
         if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
         if (conURL != null) try { conURL.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
      }  
      System.out.println("Item: " + itemNumber);
   }
```

I made sure that in my SQL Server Configuration Manager that my IP Address are all set to TCP Port 1433 and the TCP Dynamic Ports is set to blank.

I have spent many hours trying to figure this out to no success, Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks everyone

Comment: Looks like a networking problem. Can you ping the sql server host from the pi?

Comment: see that's the crazy thing, it pings just fine and has a very low ping time

Comment: from the pi, try telnet to the SQL host/port, see if telnet will connect - that's what your app is trying to do.

Comment: Well it turns out after restarting the server and the network the problem was solved. Not really sure what went wrong but it is working now, Thank you for all of the help.